# API Gateway failing to enable CORS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

When I attempt to request a lambda-backed API (using API gateway, deployed using the CLI and Cloud Development Kit) from my react app, I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/xxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/xxxxx net::ERR_FAILED
```

My API resources defined using the CDK are all passed into [this method](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/906#issuecomment-509533048)

Comment: this may seem like a silly question, but did you enable CORS in API Gateway and re-deploy the API?

Comment: @danimal yes I have tried that, but the problem is that should already be taken care of by the CDK.

Comment: Are you able to provide a snippet of the CDK code you are using to deploy the API?

Answer (score 8):

Like explain [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/906), you need to enable CORS in API Gateway, **BUT** you also need to return an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from your Lambda because API Gateway doesn't add that automatically to the responses.

Here is a sample of what my Lambda return for a simple Get :

```js
return {
  headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(response.Item),
  statusCode: 200
};

const headers = {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
}
```